# Image and Video support for Multiplatform (Android, iOS, Windows)

Tags: android, ios, converters, image-conversion, video-conversion

I know that there are [list of some supported format](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for Image, Video and Audio that an Android device play or show.

Now, I am creating an application for Android, iOS, Windows and Blackberry. There are list of supported format that each platform can either play(for Audio and Video) or show (for images). They will sync this media on Cloud. My need is that I should be able to show each and every media that what ever there extension is on my all platforms. So for that I need following information.

1. Is there any single API available (open source or paid what ever it is) which can convert these format in supportable format on my device? I googled and get to know of some APIs but I am not sure how effective they are so if any one of you have tried and know which one is best, please refer me that.
2. Also, I don't want to replicate each and every video and produce its supported version on my cloud. As I have purchased that space and don't want to waste this space just for replication of same thing. So I want that whenever a un-supported format came, It should be translated to supported version for that platform on the fly.

Please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an [Adobe AIR app](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html) (by using either *Adobe Flash Builder* or *Adobe Flash*), then it will run on Android, iOS and BlackBerry 10 (and desktop - Windows and Mac) and support same [audio and video formats](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d46.html).

Here [a nice tutorial for all platforms](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html).

[image: app photos]

Comment: But I need to create all apps using native backend languages as this app will include much more than video , audio and images sharing so I need native support for the same.